# How to print any variable value in xsl. bcoz we can not debug the xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:if test="efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Docume`efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Document' ">
```

I want to check efile_format's value. because its always getting failed when I am trying to work but tried following if condition only for viewing that if the condition is affecting or not so that's affecting

```
<xsl:if test="1">
```

Comment: Can you show the input XML structure?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are missing second or condition :

```
<xsl:if test="efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Docume`efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Document' ">
```

Corrected syntex may be like one of these:

```
<xsl:if test="efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Docume' or efile_format = 'PDF' or efile_format = 'Document' ">
```

OR

```
<xsl:if test="efile_format[(. = 'PDF') or (. = 'Document')]">
```

OR

```
<xsl:if test="efile_format=('PDF','Document')">
```

Comment: After correcting syntax it still not working. because this system is working in another file. but it's not working in this file. how to get the value of "efile_format"

Comment: I don't know XML input sample. what is that

Comment: can anyone help me